# Recursion on linkedlist : how to compare?

Tags: java, recursion, linked-list

I'm currently working on recursion in linked list and I have a question where I have to compare two numbers in a linked list and I have to do it recursively.

It return true if all the elements on the list are in an ascending order.

Here what I've done in my List :

```
public boolean ascending() {
        if(this.first == null) return false;
        return this.first.ascending();
    }
```

Here what I've done in my Cells :

```
public boolean ascending() {
        if(this.next != null) {
            if(this.employee.getNumbers() < this.next.employee.getNumbers()) return true;
            this.next.ascending();
        } return false;
    }
```

The problem is that my code return true for 100 < 200 but false for 100 < 200 < 300 and true for 100 < 200 < 100.

Any suggestion? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Your code has a mistake in it: if you return true before you call your method recursively, then you will never enter recursion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like [David Brossard](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66645866/1366871) explained you need something like:

```
public boolean ascending() 
{
        if(this.next == null)
           return true;
        else if(this.employee.getNumbers() < this.next.employee.getNumbers()) {
           return this.next.ascending();
        } 
        else return false;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I tried doing it like this however the outcome is always false. Also I don't understand why return true if next is null. Shouldn't I be false?

Comment: @Evelyne Try it now. If you reach the end it means that until then all the number where sorted like you wanted, otherwise you would have return false before

Comment: It finally works! Thank you so much I was struggling for a while with this question

Comment: @Evelyne I actually have a better approach

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your logic

You don't want to return true at all except if this.next is null because it means you ran out of numbers.

What you want to do is: for as long as I have numbers and the next one is bigger than the current one, keep looking. Otherwise return false. If I run out of numbers return true.

Comment: Awesome, I was too lazy to write the code. Thanks for picking up where I left off